# How do i include other fields in a lucene search?

Tags: lucene

Lets use emails for an example as a document. You have your subject, body, the person who its from and lets say we can also tag them (as gmail does)

From my understanding of QueryParser i give it ONE field and the parser type. If a user enter text the user only searches whatever i set. I notice it will look in the subject or body field if i wrote `fieldName: text to search` however how do i make a regular query such as "funny SO question unicorn" find result(s) with some of those strings in the subject, the others in the body? ATM because i knew it would be easy i made a field called ALL and combined all the other fields into that but i would like to know how i can do it in a proper way. Especially since my next app is text search dependent

Answer (score 2):

Use [MultiFieldQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html). You can specify list of fields to be searched using following constructor.

```
MultiFieldQueryParser(Version matchVersion, String[] fields, Analyzer analyzer)
```

This will generate a query as if you have created multiple queries on different fields. This partially addresses your problem. This, still, will not match one term matching in field1 and another matching in field2. For this, as you have rightly pointed out, you will need to combine all the fields in one single field and search in that field. Nevertheless, you will find MultiFieldQueryParser useful when query terms do not cross the field boundaries.